# TypeScript - inter-dependency decorators

Tags: typescript

From the TypeScript [docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)

> As such, the following steps are performed when evaluating multiple
>   decorators on a single declaration in TypeScript:
>
> 1. The expressions for each decorator are evaluated **top-to-bottom**. The
> 2. results are then called as functions from **bottom-to-top**.

**Problem**

I have two decorators where one decorator depends on another:

**Example**

```
@test()
@testCase({...})
public doSomething(): void {
}
```

`@testCase()` depends on `@test()` because the test need to be added to the test runner, before the test cases can be added to the test.

I could do...

```
@testCase({...})
@test()
public doSomething(): void {
}
```

but it seems odd to declare test cases before declaring that something is a test.

Is there any way to have decorators that depend on each other, i.e. a `testCase` must come after a `test`?

Comment: Is this for a library you are writing, or just one you are consuming?

Comment: @Fenton for a library I am writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add extra information to the target function in `testcase` and then check for the extra information in the `test` decorator. Below the extra information is a callback to which more decorators can contribute to. This offers a lot of flexibility, but you could add other information instead of a callback and use that information in the `test` decorator.

```
interface IAfterTestRegistered {
    afterTestRegisteredCallback?: ()=> void
}
// We could potentially have more then one contributor that need a callback executed.
function addCallback(obj: IAfterTestRegistered, callback : () => void) {
    let oldCallback = obj.afterTestRegisteredCallback;
    if(oldCallback != undefined) {
        obj.afterTestRegisteredCallback = () =>{
            oldCallback();
            callback();
        }
    }
    else{
        obj.afterTestRegisteredCallback = callback;
    }
}

function test() : MethodDecorator {
    return function<T>(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>) : void {
        console.log("test");
        let targetFunction: IAfterTestRegistered = target[propertyKey];
        if(targetFunction.afterTestRegisteredCallback) {
            targetFunction.afterTestRegisteredCallback();
        }
    }
}

function testCase(data: { index: number}) : MethodDecorator {
    return function<T>(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>) : void {
        console.log(`testcase ${data.index}`);
        addCallback(target[propertyKey], () =>
        {
            console.log(`after-register testcase ${data.index}`);
        });
    }
}

class myClass {
    @test()
    @testCase({ index: 1 })
    @testCase({ index: 2 })
    public doSomething(): void {
    }
}
// Will output
// testcase 2
// testcase 1
// test
// after-register testcase 2
// after-register testcase 1
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could remove the side-effect from the decorators and only annotate the class with metadata about the methods. Then (somewhere else) at runtime, check the class for all metadata and behave accordingly. Might scale better to multiple decorators with dependencies on each other.

Comment: @ChrisDevereux, true, that is also a good option. Feel free to add it as an answer :)

Comment: Why not just compose the two decorators into one and use that?